# jQuery UI + PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-ui, cordova

I'm writing an iPad app for the first time using jQuery UI & PhoneGap. I'm using jQuery UI over jQTouch or jQuery Mobile because I'm not trying to design an app that looks like an iOS app - it's an internal app, it needs to follow our brand, I don't want iOS style widgets or cards.

My code works fine in WebKit nightly, but not in the Xcode iPad simulator. The menu is hidden, but I can't get it to appear when the link is touched. It doesn't seem to be interpreting touch events? I'm using this addon (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/) - I assume I'm not calling it correctly? Here's my JS:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

                       // hides the secondary menu when the DOM is ready
                       $('#menu2').hide();

                       // shows the secondary menu on clicking the identified link  
                       $('#link1').click(function() {
                                         $('#menu2').show(400).addTouch();
                                         return false;
                                         });
                       });
```

& the link -

```
<a href="#" id="link1">Show Menu</a>
```

Comment: Seems possible that the addTouch call might be failing? That would cause that whole line to fail. Try removing the .addTouch() and see if the menu shows, or maybe put an alert() after the show call. Also, when I do embedded UIWebView apps, I use a window error handler, plus I have a #debug div to log stuff, and sometimes I call back into ObjC to NSLog stuff.

Comment: jQuery Mobile does not make your app look like an iOS app. You can use just the JS and the structure CSS and leave out the styling (theme) CSS. It adds a bunch of functionality that makes it easier to deal with programming on mobile devices such as your touch/click issues.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using the old html/js onclick attribute. `<a onclick="loadMenu()"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // hides the secondary menu when the DOM is ready
     $('#menu2').hide();
     // shows the secondary menu on clicking the identified link  
     $('#link1').click(function() {
        $('#menu2').show(400).addTouch();
        return false;
     });
});
```